# Scala Play implicit read catch null

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

I am using an external service and I am expecting to receive a json containing a field with three kinds of value:

- A Double
- null
- The field could be absent

I need to deserialize the json into a case class and somewhere else in the code I need to serialize it to a json with the same fields.
I have an implicit reads and write:

```
implicit lazy val aReads: Reads[A] = (
  "foo".readNullable[Double]
)(A.apply _)

implicit lazy aWrites: OWrites[A] = (
  "foo".write[Option[Double]]
)
```

and the case class:

```
case class A(
  foo: Option[Double]
)
```

As you can imagine the problem is that I am not able to "catch" when the value is absent and if a use `"foo".writeNullable[Double]` as writers I am not able to catch when it's null (it will be always absent). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What happeneds when the field is `null`? What do you serialize?

Comment: if I use the the writes `"foo".write[Option[Double]]` and I serialize it, it will be `"foo"->null` and it will be the same if it's absent.

Comment: I think I'm not following your train of thought. Do you want `"foo": null` to be serialized?

Comment: I want an output equal to the input: if I receive `"foo": null`, I would like to serialize it as null. At the same time, if the field it's absent, I don't want to have it in the output. Am I made myself clear now?

Comment: Yes, now I follow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is actually a data type which reflects three states:

- Present
- Null
- Non Existing

There is actually a [nice encoding of this here](https://github.com/drbild/tristate/blob/master/tristate-core/src/main/scala/org/davidbild/tristate/Tristate.scala), which is semantically equivalent to:

```
sealed trait Tristate[+A]
case class Present[+A](a: A) extends Tristate[A]
case object Absent extends Tristate[Nothing] // this can represent your "null" state
case object NonExisting extends Tristate[Nothing]
```

The small library linked has nice combinators over `Tristate` such as `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.

And then, you can derive a Play decoder/encoder which puts the object in the correct state serializes appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much! With the same logic, wouldn't be enought to use a Duostate wrapped in an option? In that case the trait will "capture" present and absent and the option will take care of the NonExisting. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, but the beauty of this is that you don't need `Option` at all :)

Comment: I have just finished the implementation. In the end, I decided to simply add the Tristate dependences to my project since there are also the decoder/encoder in it.

Comment: Ok. Do note that although it's a small project, I'm not sure it's maintained